# WPF usercontrols in window - dependency property value is null on doubleclick

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties, double-click

I've uploaded my sample project here: https://www.file-upload.net/download-13252079/WpfApp1.zip.html
It is a WPF window with several of the same usercontrols in it. The UserControl has a dependency property named "Text" which is bound to a MainWindowViewModel's property and successfully shows up in the UserControl's TextBlock.
However if I double-click the UserControl and want it to give the value of its dependency property, the value is null. Why is this?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Edit: sorry, here is some source code:
The UserControl's XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
         ...
         x:Name="UC1">    
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Test" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding ElementName=UC1, Path=Text}" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The UserControl's code:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { SetProperty(ref text, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1));




    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The main window's XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:UserControl1 Text="{Binding Values[0]}"
                        MouseDoubleClick="UserControl1_MouseDoubleClick">    
        </local:UserControl1>
        <local:UserControl1 Text="{Binding Values[1]}"
                        MouseDoubleClick="UserControl1_MouseDoubleClick"> 
        </local:UserControl1>
        <local:UserControl1 Text="{Binding Values[2]}"
                        MouseDoubleClick="UserControl1_MouseDoubleClick"> 
        </local:UserControl1>
        <local:UserControl1 Text="{Binding Values[3]}"
                        MouseDoubleClick="UserControl1_MouseDoubleClick"> 
        </local:UserControl1>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The main window's code behind:

```
    private void UserControl1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is UserControl1)
        {
            // why is (sender as UserControl1).Text null?
            MessageBox.Show("Text is: " + (sender as UserControl1).Text);
        }
    }
```

The main window's view model:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Values = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Values.Add("first string");
        Values.Add("second string");
        Values.Add("third string");
        Values.Add("fourth string");
    }

    #region Values

    private ObservableCollection<string> values;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Values
    {
        get { return values; }
        set { SetProperty(ref values, value); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Why did you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on Dependency Property? The firts thing is remove SetProperty<> from setter of your Text, and call it like `SetCurrentValue(TextProperty, value` and getter like `return (string)GetValue(TextPropetry)`

Comment: This is how the Dependency property should look like:        
`public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(String), typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(""));

        public String Text
        {
            get { return (String)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }`

Comment: Thank you both, that was it! I see it was stupid to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the Dependency Property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how your UserControl's code behind should look like. You do not need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

See [Custom Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties) for all the details. Specifically, you must call `GetValue` and `SetValue` (and nothing else) from the getter and setter of the `Text` property wrapper.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

For a Binding to the UserControl's Text property in its own XAML you could use `RelativeSource` instead of ElementName to save a useless generated class member:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1" ...>    
    ...
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text,
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" .../>
    ...
</UserControl>
```